# Referencing an entry created by \addcontentsline

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, l3doc

How can I reference a toc entry created with `\addcontentsline`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Foo}\label{opt:foo}
\DescribeOption{Foo}

Section~\ref{opt:foo} % Expect: % Section~0

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why l3doc as document class?

Comment: @johannes_B Tha's the context in which the issue arose. If you have to think about what could replace `\DescribeOption{Foo}` using `\documentclass{article}`, then probably more straightforward to stick to `l3doc`. I'm open to a contrary opinion.

Comment: PS: In the original, the reference appears in `\changes`. I have just realized that it works after exec the glo+index commands given in the `*log` file' (Package l3doc Info: Generate the change,,,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\label` needs the reference info in `\@currentlabel`, but `\addcontentsline` does nothing to `\@currentlabel`. You could do for instance:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{\p@section\thesection}%
\makeatother
```

or more explicitly, `\makeatletter\def\@currentlabel{0}\makeatother` (or another value) right before using `\label` to define this info, but the usual way to set `\@currentlabel` is to use `\refstepcounter`.

Since you appear to want 0 as the section number and `\refstepcounter` increments the counter *before* storing the `\protected@edef`-expansion of `\p@<counter>\the<counter>` in `\@currentlabel`, I use `\setcounter{section}{-1}` before the first `\refstepcounter{section}` call here.

```latex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mySetNameref}{\def\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\bigskip

% First option
\leavevmode
% The next “section” will be numbered 0
\setcounter{section}{-1}\refstepcounter{section}%
\mySetNameref{Option \texttt{Foo}}%
\label{opt:foo}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Foo}%
\DescribeOption{Foo} Description of \texttt{Foo}

% Second option
\leavevmode
\refstepcounter{section}%
\mySetNameref{Option \texttt{Bar}}%
\label{opt:bar}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Bar}%
\DescribeOption{Bar} Description of \texttt{Bar}

\medskip
Section~\ref{opt:foo} is named \nameref{opt:foo}. Section~\ref{opt:bar} is
named \nameref{opt:bar}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you should probably wrap this in a macro to make it more automatic.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make it work for `nameref` as well?

Comment: I've updated the example to define the `nameref` of each label.

Comment: Thanks. Why is `\leavevmode` needed?

Comment: To make sure the label (a `\write` whatsit) is in the same horizontal box as the following option from `\DescribeOption`.